# Accessing an array inside of an array

Tags: php, arrays

When trying to access an array inside an array, only NULL is output.
My Code:

```
$aStats = array();
$aStats['hd'] = array();
$aStats['hd'][] = array
(
'dev' => $device,
'total' => $total,
'used' => $used,
'free' => $free,
'used_perc' => $used_perc,
'mount' => $folder
);
echo $aStats['hd']['free'];
```

When using json_encode, the values are displayed correctly:

```
die( json_encode( $aStats ) );
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
$aStats['hd'] = array();
$aStats['hd'][] = array
```

With this:

```
$aStats['hd'] = array
```

You appear to be accessing your array (`$aStats['hd']['free'];`) as if the value of `hd` is an associated array, but using `[]` creates a new integer index in the array, and stores the value *in that index*.  Joe Walker's answer shows what happens instead, that you have an associative array pointing to an indexed array pointing to another associative array, rather than the associative to associative array you suggest you're trying to use in your `echo` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a practical tip that will let you find out where is the issue easly, all you need to do is:

```
var_dump($aStats);
```

This will output:

```
array (size=1)
  'hd' => 
   array (size=1)
    0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'dev' => string 'SomeDevice' (length=10)
      'total' => string '10000' (length=5)
      'used' => boolean true
      'free' => boolean false
      'used_perc' => string 'none' (length=4)
      'mount' => string '/some/directory/here/' (length=21)
```

Now you know you can access this element using

```
$aStats['hd'][0]['free'];
```

This will return null in your question because your variables are not yet initialized, but I guess you do have them initialized in your code, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, now i finally really understood what i was doing wrong and how i can prevent it in future !:)